# Facebook mobile HTML5 applications and Referral Authentication

Tags: facebook, mobile, oauth-2.0, facebook-canvas

I'm trying to configure my HTML5 Facebook Web application with no success.

Setup.

- I have secure and plain canvas configured at URL http(s)://fb.example.net/
- Name space is defined for canvas URL https://apps.facebook.com/*handle*
- Mobile URL is http://my.example.net/
- Referral authentication is enabled in Auth Dialog settings

What works

- Desktop Canvas integration (I get POST with signed_request parameter and can exchange that to access token)
- Facebook connect. Business as usual.

What does not work

1. FB iOS app 4.1 on iPhone 3Gs sends user to http://my.example.net/?ref=bookmark&refid=8&pos=1. I understood from Referral Auth documentation that I would get URL parameter 'code' that I can exchange to access token. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/web/#login
2. FB iPad app on iPad v1 sends user to http://fb.example.net/?ref=bookmark&refid=8&pos=1. Also no 'code' parameter here.
3. m.facebook.com on iPhone Safari works like Case (1). I've seen it to redirect my.example.net occasionally??
4. m.facebook.com on iPad Safari works like Case (2)

In all cases authentication dialog is not shown. This bug might be related: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/364761150204975

What I expect to happen.

In all cases 1-4 mobile users are redirected to my.example.net with 'code' parameter defined in URL. New user will see the authentication dialog before redirection as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/ and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/web/#login

Is there something wrong with by setup, or something that I don't understand here?

Basic Settings
[image: Basic Settings]

Auth Dialog Settings
[image: Auth Dialog Settings]

Advanced Settings 1/2
[image: Advanced Settings 1/2]

Advanced Settings 2/2
[image: Advanced Settings 2/2]